# GXServer, como migrar os usuários de uma instância EVL2 para EVL3?

Tags: genexus

Migração para GX Server EVL3.

Como fazer a migração de usuários registrados como local no GXServer do Evl2 para uma nova instância do EVL3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Existe um utilitário chamado [GeneXus Server Storage Migration Tool](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?18169) que permite levar essa definição para uma nova versão do GXserver.

Recomendo ler este artigo : 
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?18170